# Image displayed from json disappears when route is changed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm displaying the json value on the image using div tag, but the json values are disappearing when i go to other pages and returning to home page.
I am developing it with Angular.js

```
NumberJson.get().then(function (result) {
  if (result) {
    $sessionStorage.testNumber = result[0]['testNumber'];
    $scope.testNumber = $sessionStorage.testNumber;

    $sessionStorage.testNumber1 = result[0]['testNumber1'];
    $scope.testNumber1 = $sessionStorage.testNumber1;
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you make use of ngRoute and separate controller for each page as per relative url?

Comment: <a ui-sref="user" href="#/user">
   <img ng-src="./folder1/images/User.png"/>
   <div class="users" >{{testNumber}}</div><br>
   <center>Number of USER</center>
</a><br>

Comment: Oh you make use of ui-router. Just try placing the value in $rootScope instead of $scope. Json would probably be available throughtout.

Comment: Hi Gayathri,Thanks for the response , you are absolutely right. I have tried the same and its working..Yes i am using separate controller for relative URL under .state (state provider). Thanks for your Help..

Comment: My pleasure! I once faced a the same issue at work and hence got to know this. I just added the same as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Place the value in $rootScope instead of $scope.
 It would make json available throughout the application, though you make use of separate controller for each relative URL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Gayathri will work but there are better solutions.

**1. One controller for a fixed top bar**

If the data you want to show will be displayed in a specific area you can create a controller/views for this area. Inside the controller you can call the service to retrieve your json.

**2. Call the service where you need it**

If you need this info on some pages only, you can put the function in a service available to all controllers. You can then call it from the controller where you need it